# Integrate E-mail validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, email, spam

Can someone help me spam proof this PHP script? Also, when I use this script I get two emails, one empty and the other with the results.

```
<?php 
    $to = "voodoocastde@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Registrierung auf voodooCAST.de";
    $headers = "From: Form Mailer";
    $forward = 0;
    $location = "";

    $date = date ("l, F jS, Y"); 
    $time = date ("h:i A"); 



    $msg = "Below is the result of your feedback form. It was submitted on $date at $time.\n\n"; 

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
            $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n"; 
        }
    }
    else {
        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) { 
        $msg .= ucfirst ($key) ." : ". $value . "\n"; 
        }
    }

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers); 
    if ($forward == 1) { 
        header ("Location:$location"); 
    } 
    else { 
        header( 'Location: http://www.voodoocast.de/confirm.php' ) ;     
    } 

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "spam-proof"?

Comment: Spam proof would mean that you could only enter Valid email adresses and wouldn't be able to inject scripts into that form or something

Answer (score 0):

in your html form you can use `<input type="email"></input>` and it will validate itself

Comment: And how do I fix the problem of me getting 2 emails each time I submit the form?

Comment: in which variables do you get those emails ?

Comment: <div id="signup">
     <div id="signupform">
   <form action="mailer.php" method="post">
              
              <input name="name" type="text" value="Name..." onfocus="clearIt(this)" onblur="setIt(this)" maxlength="50" id="input">
              
              <input name="email" type="email" value="E-Mail adresse..." onfocus="clearIt(this)" onblur="setIt(this)" maxlength="50" id="input">
              
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="" id="submit">
    </form>
      </div><!--close SIGNUPFORM-->
    </div><!--close SIGNUP-->

Comment: Why don't you add it to the main question so the code can be more easy to read